# Compare 2 tables and check if number exist

Tags: c#

I have 2 tables with random numbers and i want to check which number from first table doesn't exist in second one and output it.

```
Example:
First table: 2, 6, 7, 9
Second table: 0, 6, 11, 3

Output: 2, 7, 9
```

My current code:

```
#region CompareTables

            int[,] TABLE1 = new int[5, 10];
            int[,] TABLE2 = new int[5, 10];

            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    TABLE1[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
                    TABLE2[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
                }
            }

            Console.Write("TABLE1" + "\n\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    Console.Write(TABLE1[i, j] + " " + "\t");
                    Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("TABLE2" + "\n\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    Console.Write(TABLE2[i, j] + " " + "\t");
                    Console.WriteLine();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    if (TABLE1[i, j] == TABLE2[i, j])

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
#endregion
```

I would like to ask how to output numbers that are in first table but not in second?

Comment: Why is it again tagged C? Do you understand why I did that? Ok that's it. I won't edit again this question.

Comment: This is c# not c .. i approved edit from @Yanet Pedraza and he/she changed to c

Comment: @faca table is 2d or 1d

Comment: @yajiv it's 2d.

Comment: Once you define an 2 demintional array you have to use both indexes to get a value.

Comment: @faca one way is to use brute force,

Comment: @juharr yes i completely forgot about that but still i'm struggling how to output number which doesnt exist in second table

Comment: @yajiv i want to make it as simple as possible (without bruteforce:D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could covert your 2D arrays into lists and find the numbers from `TABLE1` that don't exist in `TABLE2` with LINQ `Except`:

```
List<int> LIST1 = TABLE1.Cast<int>().ToList();
List<int> LIST2 = TABLE2.Cast<int>().ToList();

var result = LIST1.Except(LIST2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that your tables are 2 dimensional arrays and you are trying to index into them as if they were one dimensional arrays.

Look at how your are filling them up:

```
TABLE1[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
TABLE2[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
```

You are correctly using *two* indexes `i` and `j` (think of rows and columns).

However, later on you are doing:

```
if (TABLE1[1] == TABLE2[i])  //where is the second index?
```

This is obviously wrong, but instead of making this work, lets take a step back and think this through again. All this mucking around with two indexes seems a little... yeah, mucky, shouldn't there be a better way to do this?

In your current problem, the fact that the tables are multidimensional is simply a pain that doesn't really add any value. If you only need to return elements of the first table that are not present in the second table without any position information, then why all this hassle with indexes to begin with? Lets create a helper method that flattens the arrays and enables us to get rid of at least one index:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T[,] array)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
           yield return array[i, j];
}
```

And now that we have one dimensional arrays (`IEnumerable<T>`s) we can leverage C#'s magic stick...LINQ! Solving your problem is as simple as:

```
var notPresent = TABLE1.Flatten().Except(TABLE2.Flatten());
```

But this can have horrible performance if the arrays are big enough. Remember how you would solve this problem by hand (and how `Except` does it too): take first element from table 1, check all elements from table 2 until you either find a match or there are no more elements. Take second element from table 1, check all elements from table 2 until... etc. That seems a lot of work, and it grows really fast if the tables are big. Also if your are not smart about it you might be doing unnecessary extra work because Table 1 and 2 might contain duplicate elements...

Can this be improved? Yes, there are specially built collections that allow really fast searches; *Sets*. In your case, a `HashSet<int>` seems like a pretty good choice.

Your code now would look like:

```
var set = new HashSet<int>(TABLE1.Flatten());
var notPresent = set.Except(TABLE2.Flatten());
```

And this will perform much better.

Comment: well i'm doing this way to make it as simple as it can be .. your way is too hard to understand (for me) but i appreciate that you helped..